# Changing camera declaration to avoid .sks file

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code inside `didMoveToView()` which relies on a .sks file to work properly:

```
if let camera : SKCameraNode = self.childNodeWithName("Camera") as? SKCameraNode {

        theCamera = camera
        self.camera = theCamera

    }
```

I don't want to use .sks files anymore (extremely buggy and dangerous) so I tried with this instead:

```
if let camera : SKCameraNode = SKCameraNode() {
        camera.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)

        theCamera = camera
        self.camera = theCamera

        }
```

The result is the exclusion of all children to the camera node and a majority of the non-camera scene children. I have not been able to tell what defines this group these nodes that are not visible.
How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using the .sks file anymore, you need to manually add the camera to your scene.

`self.addChild(theCamera)` will do the trick.